# Tracking offline event with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I tried to track user activity in my site such as click or mouse over and different kind of events....
Is there any solution to track events even when users are working offline...
Can I store them in something like cookie and send them to the server when find active internet connection?

Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depends on what browser types you're targeting. Are these for HTML5 offline webapps?

If they [support `ononline` and `onoffline` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Online_and_offline_events), you can implement this yourself fairly trivially.

Some potentially workable code, using offline events, native JSON and HTML5 Local Storage:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("offlineGA")){
  localStorage.setItem("offlineGA","[]");
}
var _ogaq = {
push : function(arr){
    if(navigator.onLine || !("onLine" in navigator)){ // if online or if browser doesn't support onLine/offLine detection.
        _gaq.push(arr);
    }
    else{
     var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("offlineGA"));
     stored.push(arr);
     localStorage.setItem("offlineGA", JSON.stringify(stored));
    }
}
};

$(window).bind("online", function(){ // if you don't have jQuery, you can do window.ononline instead
   _gaq.push( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("offlineGA")) );
   localStorage.setItem("offlineGA","[]"); //empty it
});
```

Then you would just use `_ogaq` as a wrapper for `_gaq`.

ie:

```
_ogaq.push(["_trackEvent","Category", "Action"]);
```

Comment: If you try to fire more than 10 hits to GA in a short period it will be dropped, and only the first 10 will be sent. It means that for this code if you stay offline for too long and query more than 10 events/pageviews, only the first 100 will actually go to GA once you get online

Comment: Ooh, good call. I'll work on adding a setInverval to loop through them at a staggered rate :)

Comment: Also, it's important to note that Google analytics is tracking more than just simple events: things such as the time an event took place as well as other session-related stuff which will be gone or out of context by the time the user comes back online.  The real solution would be to generate the actual image beacon code and embed those images when the user comes back online... I will see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: Did anyone develop a full featured offline GA support lib yet, taking all these comment into account?

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to consider is that the time that would get recorded would be the time the data was sent as opposed to collected locally on the device. Fortunately however there is now a way to avoid this being an issue using the measurement protocol and the qt parameter (queue time) it allows you to send the age of the event/view etc.. in milliseconds. I have tried this in the realtime viewer and it does show up at the time recorded as expected.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt

Realise it's an old question but it has been driving me bonkers this weekend.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this helpful as well. ononline/offline is not as reliable as one might think.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=67e8cf894a003c64&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

according to this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/offline-google-analytics?hl=en), offline behaviour is supported by the google offline. 
you have just to add these library

```
    npm install --save-dev sw-offline-google-analytics
    ...
    importScripts('path/to/offline-google-analytics-import.js');
    goog.offlineGoogleAnalytics.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not work for me, so i found out, that the GA push of the array did not work correctly. 
So i looped the array, pushed each entry to Google Analytics. Now it works like a charm ...

```
$(window).bind("online", function(){ // if you don't have jQuery, you can do window.ononline instead

   var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("offlineGA"));

   for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {    
        _ogaq.push([json[i][0],json[i][1], json[i][2]]);
    }

   localStorage.setItem("offlineGA","[]"); //empty it
   var json = "";
});
```